# Playing audio with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer, file-manager

I'm currently downloading audio files from Firebase saving them locally and listing them in a tableview. Im getting the local directory like this:

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6C72433F-4DF0-4976-BBDE-36F6B5C23E6D/Documents/nJNJwVNMrmUGj9uszManQmMOZf52_NO:1.m4a

When i try to play an audio file with AVAudioPLayer i get the error:

Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003334207 "(null)"

I've been stuck on this for three days and would really appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction. If any further code is needed to help solve this let me know. Thanks.

This is my code for playing the audio:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //Access the cell tapped on and the path to the recording the user wants to listen to
    let path = findDirectory(filename:userID + "_NO:" + String(recordingNumber)).appendingPathComponent("\(indexPath.row + 1).m4a")

    do {
        self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: path)
        self.audioPlayer.play()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.description)
    }
}
```

My code for finding the directory is here:

```
func findDirectory(filename:String) -> URL {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let urls = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let docDirectory = urls[0] as URL
    let soundURL = docDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(filename).m4a")
    print(soundURL)
    return soundURL
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file you download is saved as `nJNJwVNMrmUGj9uszManQmMOZf52_NO:1.m4a` why are you appending on top of it through: `.appendingPathComponent("\(indexPath.row + 1).m4a")` this value `<row_value + 1>.m4a` in your tableview?

Its like now you are trying to find a file saved as: `nJNJwVNMrmUGj9uszManQmMOZf52_NO:1.m4a<row_value + 1>.m4a`.

Here `<row_value + 1>` is a placeholder I used in this answer to show you the meaning but in real code will be replaced by either a value like `1`, `2`,...

To explain it better let's analyse:

```
let path = findDirectory(filename:userID + "_NO:" + String(recordingNumber)).appendingPathComponent("\(indexPath.row + 1).m4a")
```

- 1. `userID + "_NO:"` will produce something like: `nJNJwVNMrmUGj9uszManQmMOZf52_NO:`
- 2. `String(recordingNumber)` will produce something like: `1` (for example)
- 3. and doing `findDirectory(filename: ...)` with the above will give you back `nJNJwVNMrmUGj9uszManQmMOZf52_NO:1.m4a` as of the line `let soundURL = docDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(filename).m4a")`
- 4. now on top of it, you do `.appendingPathComponent("\(indexPath.row + 1).m4a")` which appends more to your path that looked already completed

You'd likely want to modify the logic to better match how you expect the path to work with your tableview, so that you compose the right path for your file (maybe that means in your case removing the extra appending you do in step 4)

Comment: Taking out the .appendingPathComponent("\(indexPath.row + 1).m4a") fixed my problem! Thank you